# Duplicate keys in memcached

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, memcached

I'm having some trouble with memcache on my php site.  Occasionally I'll get a report that the site is misbehaving and when I look at memcache I find that a few keys exist on both servers in the cluster.  The data is not the same between the two entries (one is older).

My understanding of memcached was that this shouldn't happen...the client should hash the key and then always pick the same server.  So either my understanding is wrong or my code is.  Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

FWIW the servers are hosted on Amazon EC2.

All my connections to memcache are opened through this function:

```
$mem_servers = array(
    array('ec2-000-000-000-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 11211, 50),
    array('ec2-000-000-000-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 11211, 50)
);

function ConnectMemcache()
{
     global $mem_servers;
     if ($memcon == 0) {
          $memcon = new Memcache();
          foreach($mem_servers as $server) $memcon->addServer($server[0], $server[1], true);
     }
     return($memcon);
}
```

and values are stored through this:

```
function SetData($key,$data)
{
    global $mem_global_key;
    if(MEMCACHE_ON_OFF)
    {
        $key = $mem_global_key.$key;
        $memcache = ConnectMemcache();
        $memcache->set($key, $data);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this blog post touches on the problems your having.

http://www.caiapps.com/duplicate-key-problem-in-memcache-php/

From the article it sounds like the following happens:
- a memcache server that has the key originally drops out
- the key is recreated on the 2nd server with updated data
- 1st server come back online and into the cluster with the old data.
- Now you have the keys save on 2 servers with different data

Sounds like you may need to use Memcache::flush to clear out the memcache cluster before your write to help minimize how long duplicates might exist in your cluster.